# Android - ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout> : The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I'm using an ArrayAdapter with LinearLayout as generic:

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout> {

private Context context;

public TestAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_result);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_result, parent, false);
        // configure view holder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.row = (FrameLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.result_row);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.row.removeAllViews();
    viewHolder.row.addView(getItem(position));
    return rowView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    FrameLayout row;
}}
```

My problem is: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

LinearLayout is a horizontal wrapper for imageView's dinamically created.

This is my error. Seems to be at : viewHolder.row.addView(getItem(position));

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3577)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3375)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3351)
        at com.dreamstime.buyer.picture.adapter.TestAdapter.getView(TestAdapter.java:43)
        at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2308)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2132)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14858)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4646)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2035)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1792)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1047)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: a staggered layout only with images, images have same height but different width, and one row can have 2 , 3 or 4 images... My solutions its work but i have this issue

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

<strike>rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_result, parent, false);</strike>

to this:

```
rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_result, null, false);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Passing in the parent simply indicates the LayoutParam to inherit. It's the third argument which could cause this error if it was true.  As that actually says whether to attach to the parent or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use a `View` as the object stored in an adapter.  An adapter is meant to link data to views. By using:

```
extends ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout>
```

you are eliminating the data part.  Also, this breaks down how `View` generation happens.  Since you are trying to display Images, you should be using `BitMaps` or `Drawables`.  Then in the `getView` method, you want to add those images to whichever `View` in your inflated `row_result` layout.

You mentioned wanting to create a staggered layout. This is a very difficult thing to do. I suggest using [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) instead of trying to roll your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers, but i found a solution.

```
  viewHolder.row.removeAllViews();
    if(current != null){
        ViewGroup p = (ViewGroup) current.getParent();
        if (p != null) {
            p.removeView(current);
        }
        viewHolder.row.addView(current);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that question is already not actual. But I had the same problem with error "**children already has a parent**" while I was trying dynamically add multiple view (from List<**View**>) inside ListView with the help of adapter.

I didn't find the "ready" solution for me. I have made my own solution from pieces of code I have found. Here what has helped me:

1) inside "**getView**" create **layout** programatically for every **view** that you want to add to your **listview**. Add you view to this *layout*, then add this *layout* to **scrollView** (also programatically created).

2) make **convertView**=scrollView.

*ConvertView from here -> getView(LayoutInflater inflater, **View convertView**,ViewGroup parent)*

3) don't forget use "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()" after changing your List<**View**>.

Also [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27588017/4042420) needed to.

Hope my post will be usefull.